# How to instantiate a class, written in theme, in wordpress plugin?

Tags: wordpress, class, oop, plugins, themes

I have a class `abc` in

```
wp-content/themes/classes/
```

and I want to instantiate that class in

```
wp-content/plugins/myplugin/
```

I am a newbie to wordpress, pardon me if this is too basic.

Answer (score 1):

include at top of plugin page you file as

```
$include=get_template_directory_uri()."/classes/yourfile.php";
include($include);
```

and make a object of class

```
$obj = new class_name;
```

and use this function.

Answer (score 1):

What error are you getting?

Is the class actually in

```
wp-content/themes/classes/
```

or in a specific theme? Yatendra's answer will attempt to load

```
wp-content/themes/current_theme/classes/file.php
```

Try something like

```
if ( !class_exists( 'abc' ) ) {
    include_once( WP_CONTENT_DIR . /themes/classes/file.php );
}

$abc = new abc();
```